# Problems trying to upgrade from version 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, ppa, update-manager

OK, I'm trying to update my current installation 17.10 (it was a fresh instalation) and I'm following the ubuntu tutorial to update [(This one)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.59976493.1223268025.1526478191-1614606343.1519910210) . But when I open the Software Updater gives me this error:

### Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection.

Information give this:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I've already unchecked the PPA in the Update options but after that Software Updater says `Your computer it's up to date`

Also tried `update-manager -c` & `sudo do-release-upgrade -cd` but prompt gives me "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release."

And when `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk` nothing ocurrs, just

```
PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:timeout reached, exiting
```

Comment: First I had the same problem (Your computer is Up-To-Date), but later (after few days),  the upgrade was automatically available (Message-Box was shown, something like: **Would you like to upgrade?**)...

Comment: Are you sure your Internet connection (including DNS) is working correctly?  i.e., can you `sudo ping` the respository in Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the repository...

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu artful Release
```

to read...

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic Release
```

And in Software & Updates, make sure this is not selected...

[image]

Comment: So simple and helpful, thanks that solve the issue.

I'vs just change both ppas, normal and Source and after the updates the message appeared. So much thanks.